# no such module 'SQLite' from playground

Tags: sqlite.swift

I have downloaded SQLite.swift and get this error:

Playground execution failed: /var/folders/43/nc3kf6y17dbfdn14crfmcdjh0000gn/T/./lldb/2060/playground2.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'SQLite'
import SQLite

I also note that SQLite.swift has a reference to sqlcipher.xcodeproj. Do I need to include this too?

Even with the playground in SQLite I get the same error.

I am using Xcode 7.1 Beta with the c9d3082 commit of SQLite.swift

Have followed your instructions precisely.

Many thanks

Now solved. Here is the answer:
1) Make sure "Framework Search Paths" in Build Settings for your project is set to the workspace where SQLite is loaded. In my system I had them in the same workspace
2) Get rid of the additional info from Per-configuration Build Products Path. My just says: "$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)"
3. IN SQLite, Clean then rebuild. Then run Tests. Make sure SQLite.framework is not coloured red under Products in SQLite.xcodeproj
4. Then follow Stephen's steps 1 to 4.
5. I am using Xcode 7.2 Beta

Comment: Have you built the framework, first? Playgrounds that use frameworks expect them to be built and do not build them manually.

Comment: Whilst now I no longer get the @no such module" message, I get the following: "error: use of unresolved identifier 'Connection'
let db=try! Connection()". I built your framework before following your other instructions. The build was successful. Putting "let db=try! Connection()" into a swift file gets no errors. Just the playground has issues.

Comment: I have now solved my issue. The details are added above. For some reason this version of Xcode does not like "db.trace(print)" in the playground. Plus there is a "self." needed to be added in one of the modules (sorry - I forget which)

Comment: Stephen - This is the module that needs changing:
    func test_commitHook_setsCommitHook() {
        async { done in
            db.commitHook {
                done()
            }
            try! db.transaction {
                try self.InsertUser("alice")
            }
            XCTAssertEqual(1, db.scalar("SELECT count(*) FROM users") as? Int64)
        }
    }

Comment: Try changing that to `db.trace { print($0) }` instead. Needs to be fixed upstream.

Comment: Hi @stephencelis I have added SQLite.swift as a git submodule, and configured my project so it can `import SQLite`. But when I open the SQLite.playground file, it says in the console "Playground execution failed: /var/folders/jl/yprcnzkd53g0d3nsmts8p6r40000gn/T/./lldb/35394/playground16.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'SQLite'". I noticed your first comment, but didn't really get it. Could you give me a hint? Many thanks.